# 13-hours night layover in Paris

Tags: paris, nightlife

I have a connecting flight with night stay in Paris. I'm going to get to the city. I have already been in Paris, so I've seen the Eiffel Tower and famous tourists sights. Are there any places worth visiting at night?

Comment: Have you seen the famous tourist sights at night?

Comment: I would be happy to see them again anyway

Comment: I am pretty sure we have had this or a closely related question before but can not search now.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119317/12-hour-layover-in-paris-10-pm-to-10-am/119341#119341

Comment: What's your actual timing? What airport(s) are you arriving at/departing from? I suppose you are planning to sleep at some point? Have you already picked a place to stay (in Paris, or near the airport)? Will you have luggage to carry? Do you like walking? What period of the year and what day of the week are we talking about? Of course if you're planning to arrive this Saturday your plans may be quite different :-(